# Npm - .jsTypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function

Tags: laravel-5, npm, webpack

When I run npm run watch or npm run dev I get the following error:

> > @ watch /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock
> >     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js  10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active. Webpack is watching the files…
>
> 10% building modules 6/8 modules 2 active
>   …/stock/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.jsTypeError:
>   dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function
>       at addDependency (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:402:30)
>       at iterationOfArrayCallback (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:88:3)
>       at addDependenciesBlock (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:422:5)
>       at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:433:4)
>       at afterBuild (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:560:16)
>       at _this.buildModule.err (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:606:11)
>       at callback (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:357:35)
>       at module.build.error (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:393:12)
>       at handleParseResult (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:369:12)
>       at doBuild.err (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:391:6)
>       at runLoaders (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:270:12)
>       at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:370:3
>       at iterateNormalLoaders (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:211:10)
>       at Array. (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:202:4)
>       at Storage.finished (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
>       at provider (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
>       at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stock/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:532:3) ^C%

I’ve tried to reinstall npm and tried to switch back to a lower npm/webpack version but that didn’t help.

Deleted the node_modules and did `npm cache clean --force` + `npm install` but that didn't work as well.

The last thing I did before this error came up was `install sass loader`, to fix an error with sass.
When I delete the `sass loader` I still getting this error.

My package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "iview": "^2.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.6.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

My webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Node version:** v9.8.0

**Npm version:** 5.8.0

**OS:** MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

**Laravel framework:** 5.4.36

Comment: Is it related to this issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6675

Comment: Yes, saw the issue and downgradet my webpack version like they say, but that didn't fix the issue for me.